# GDALINFO not displaying what is in .TFW file

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, osgeo

I'm trying to alter the metadata in a Geotiff header via a .tfw file. When I change Pixel Size in the .tfw file, that is reflected in GDALINFO how I would expect.

However, when I change the Origin Value in the tfw file, GDALINFO is not displaying exactly what I type in the .tfw file. It's displaying a long float value. I'm ok with having repeating zeros like the Pixel Size data but I can't have random numbers like the Origin value.

[image]

and when I run GDALINFO I get these results..

[image]

Any ideas why what I put in the .tfw file isn't displaying in GDALINFO.

**EDIT

I've tried using Python to resolve this issue but still not getting desired results.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst

tiff_path = r"E:\temp\fran\pizelsize\test.tif"

data2 = gdal.OpenShared(tiff_path, gdalconst.GA_Update)

geoTransform_tuple = data2.GetGeoTransform()
list_of_tuple = list(geoTransform_tuple)

for x in list_of_tuple:
    print x

print '\n'

origin_X = round(list_of_tuple[0], 3)
origin_Y = round(list_of_tuple[3], 3)
res_X = round(list_of_tuple[1], 4)
res_Y = round(list_of_tuple[5], 4)

list_of_tuple[0] = origin_X
list_of_tuple[3] = origin_Y
list_of_tuple[1] = res_X
list_of_tuple[5] = res_Y


for x in list_of_tuple:
    print x

data2.SetGeoTransform(list_of_tuple)
data2 = None
```

I've tried setting everything to a float. I've tried using the Decimal module. I've tried converting to string then back to float. I get the desired result *displayed* in python. But when I try to write it to the tiff, only Pixel Size gets updated.

[image]

The second output is what I want in the tiff. But GDALINFO gives me this.

[image]

Pixel Size updated, Origin either not updated or calculated some other way.

Comment: This belongs to World File trivia. Origin that is used in TFW is placed at the middle of the top-left pixel while GDAL puts it into the top-left corner of the top-left pixel. Therefore you will get 15 cm shift and a rather small rounding error. No need to worry.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the response. I'm really just trying to change that Origin value in GDALINFO. I thought going the .TFW route would be simple. I've tried a lot of different things including updating the geotransform values via Python but I never get a clean result. It's always that floating number.

Comment: Then the value you want probably can't be represented exactly by binary numbers.

Comment: If that's the case, I would also expect the Pixel Size field to behave the same way. I can get the Pixel Size to update how I want. It just adds a bunch of zeros on the end which is fine.

Comment: Pixel size is used as is. Origin is computed as (world file originX) - (pixel size/2) and (world file originY) + (pixel size/2). If you need to set the origin exactly don't use TFW but set it directly to GDAL geotransform with Python or something http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html. You wrote you could not make it work so please show your python code, But what issues do you have now? The origin value is not "random". Doesn't rounding to a bit less desimal places work for you?

Comment: added code to the body of the question.